# How to fetch data from database and store into variable in laravel

Tags: laravel-8

```
$bookHourly = new CarOnRent;
if ($request->bookingType == 2){
    $if_hourly = CarOnRent::where(['cityName' => $request->cityName, 'carName' => $request->carName, 'bookingDate' => $request->bookingDate, 'fromTime' => $request->fromTime,'toTime' => $request->toTime])->first();
    $startTime = '';
    $endTime = '';
}
```

I want to fetch data from database and store into $startTime and $endTime.
I've table columns fromTime and toTime. I want data of fromTime into $startTime and toTime into $endTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$if_hourly` object which one get data from database

```
$bookHourly = new CarOnRent;
if ($request->bookingType == 2){
    $if_hourly = CarOnRent::where(['cityName' => $request->cityName, 'carName' => $request->carName, 'bookingDate' => $request->bookingDate, 'fromTime' => $request->fromTime,'toTime' => $request->toTime])->first();
    $startTime = $if_hourly->fromTime;
    $endTime = $if_hourly->toTime';
}
```

Use

```
$startTime = $if_hourly->fromTime;
$endTime = $if_hourly->toTime';
```